# How can i translate this code written from php in adonisJS?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, adonis.js

I have a bunch of code in PHP, and I want to translate it into AdonisJS.

I have a table from a database here and I want to make a migration to Adonis with this code.

This is the default code in PHP:

```
$schema = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema();
  $myTable = $schema->createTable("user_comenzi");
  $myTable->addColumn("id", "integer", array("unsigned" => true,"autoincrement"=>true));
  $myTable->addColumn("user_id", "integer", array("unsigned" => true));
  $myTable->addColumn("adresa_id", "integer", array("unsigned" => true));
  $myTable->addColumn("creat", "datetime", array());
  $myTable->addColumn("status", "integer", array("default"=>0));
  $myTable->addColumn("comanda", "text");
  $myTable->setPrimaryKey(array("id"));
  //$schema->createSequence("comenzi_seq");
  $platform = new  \Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SqlitePlatform();
  $queries = $schema->toSql($platform); // get queries to create this schema.
  print_r($queries);
  $app['db']->query($queries[0]);
```

And it's supposed to be something like this in AdonisJS:

```
class UserComenziSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('user_comenzi', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('user_id').unsigned()
      table.integer('adresa_id').unsigned()
      table.time('creat')
      table.integer('status').defaultTo(0)
      table.text('comanda')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('user_comenzi')
  }
}
```

I want just to see if my code is wrong or not, and if I'm wrong, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `table.time('creat')` to `table.datetime('creat')` and you are ready